# Residue at $z=0$ for the complex function $8z^2\sin(\frac{1}{z})$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm just learning calculating residue please help.

Comment: Does the 8 have any impact on the answer?

Comment: Yes, it gets multiplied by $8$. So for your case we have $\text{Res}(f,0)=-\frac{8}{6}=-\frac{4}{3}.$

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome! :-)